# UV Packing texel density

Tags: uv, add-on, transforms, unreal-engine, packing

**Is there any way to pack UV or organise UV islands without changing there UV scale?**
I'm trying to configure a whole scene with 20.48/cm UV texel density.
But when i try to automate the storage of my UVs by packing, it always try to fit the entire UV space and change the texel density of the islands.
Thanks.